# Insert into newly created column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a Students table with 2 col as Rollno and Marks with 12 records
I added another column in students table as Name. How do I fill Names with 12 records from another table in SQL Server?

I  tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM [SampleDB].[dbo].[Student_SQL]
```

```
insert into Student_SQL(name)
select name
FROM [School].[dbo].[StudentMaster]
```

```
update [Student_SQL]  
set name = 'David'
where RollNo = 4`
```

Comment: Which database are you running: sqlserver, mysql, sqlite..? And which column can be used to relate the two tables?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the upate/join syntax. Assuming that the two tables relate through column `rollno`:

```
update ss
set ss.name = sm.name
from student_sql ss
inner join student_master sm on sm.rollno = ss.rollno
```

The upside of this approach is that it filters the rows and only update those that match in the master table.

Answer (score 0):

in order to do this, you need to have column in common for both tables

```
update [Student_SQL] s
set name = (select name from other_table o where o.roll_no = s.roll_no)
```